# Get css class list from style tag

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net

I want to get list of classes being used inside a style tag and append to a drop down later. I have the below code in my ASPX page

```html
<style id="pageStyleCss" type="text/css">
  body {
    color: black;
  }
  
  .testclass1 {
    height: 100px;
  }
  
  .testclass2 {
    height: 100px;
    color: red;
  }
  
  #testid {
    color: black;
  }
</style>


var resultarray= [];

var a = $('#pageStyleCss').html();

while (a.indexOf('{') != -1) {

resultarray.push(a.substring(0, a.indexOf('{')));

a = a.substring(a.indexOf('}') + 1);
}
```

```
The output I want is:
Class list :  testclass1,testclass2
```

Comment: That was not what I asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Below code helped me getting my requirement.   

  var resultarray = [];
        var a = $('#pageStyleCss').html();
        if (a != undefined) {
            while (a.indexOf('{') != -1) {
                resultarray.push(a.substring(0, a.indexOf('{')));
                a = a.substring(a.indexOf('}') + 1);
            }
        }
        var i, option = "<option value=''></option>"
        for (i = 0; i < resultarray.length; ++i) {
            if (resultarray[i].indexOf('.') > -1) {
                option += '<option value="' + resultarray[i].trim().replace('.', '') + '">' + resultarray[i].trim().replace('.', '') + '</option>';
            }
        }
```